# Как скрыть консоль процесса из python программы?

Tags: python, процесс

Есть gui приложение на python, в котором я запускаю процесс шахматного движка, используя библиотеку python chess library, запускаю командой:

```
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("H:/stockfish_9_x64.exe")
```

Затем я собрал exe из исходников на python, проблема в том, что когда запускается процесс движка, появляется его консоль. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы она не появлялась? Как я понимаю, нужно узнать PID этого процесса (по его имени), а затем, используя его, скрыть консоль. Не подскажите, как это проще всего сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: С помощью чего собирали `.exe`?

Comment: С помощью pyinstaller

Comment: попробуйте компилировать не .py файл, а .pyw файл

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы консоль не открывалась при сборке `.exe` с помощью pyinstaller, необходимо:

1. Сначала создать файл `.spec` (`pyi-makespec имя_Вашего_скрипта`)
2. Там, к сожалению, не помню, в каком именно виде, есть параметр наподобие `console = True`. Смените `True` на `False`
3. Теперь запустите `pyinstaller имя_Вашего_скрипта.spec` (**`.spec` а не `.py`**)

Либо можно сделать ещё проще: `pyinstaller --noconsole имя_вашего_скрипта.py`

Comment: Я так и собирал (pyinstaller --noconsole имя_вашего_скрипта.py), это подавляет лишь консоль главного приложения, но не движка.

Comment: @user347195 Тогда могу посоветовать только в настройках движка искать

Comment: К сожалению, там нет таких настроек (это консольное приложение), мне кажется, как я уже писал, нужно узнать PID процесса движка и по нему закрыть его консоль. Мне казалось, что это несложно сделать (например, с помощью тех же WinApi функций или с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки python).

Comment: @user347195 Про pid тут: https://toster.ru/q/596997 про убийство процесса тут: https://python-scripts.com/question/4573

Comment: Спасибо, только убивать процесс мне не надо, надо лишь скрыть его консоль. А про PID - сейчас попробую.

Comment: PID вроде получил, спасибо, теперь буду искать, как подавить консоль.

Comment: @user347195 Рад, что хоть чем-то помог